# Restrict requests by HTTP referer - IIS

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

I have an IIS website at mydomain.com/mywebsite which has a URL rewrite request that for any requests to a 'maps' path (mydomain.com/mywebsite/maps) through the website, it will redirect requests to an external site to retrieve mapping image tiles that display on the page.

If someone tries to go to mydomain.com/mywebsite/maps on their browser, I do not want it to be accessible as I want to restrict these requests only to the website.

How can I set up a restrict rule in IIS to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a request blocking rule for this, here a example for you as reference:

```
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
       <conditions>
          <add input="{URL}" pattern="^maps$" />
       </conditions>
    <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

Comment: thanks for this - wouldn't this block all requests to the maps path, even through the website?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to restrict access to the URL path by adding an HTTP_REFERER condition in my URL inbound rewrite rule so it only accepts requests from my website domain which seems to work.

```
<conditions>
     <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="*mywebsite.com*" />
</conditions>
```